# Is there any server or software that legitimately improves a site's SEO?

Tags: seo, blackhat

I started to learn about SEO in last four months. Before that I was just a freelance web designer.

Since I am new to this industry, I contacted a SEO company to optimize our client's website which I designed. While discussing SEO with the company one of the technical staff told me that they have some sort of server which boosts the website and they can achieve good results in a short amount of time.

I don't really believe what he said so I want to know whether any such system or server exists which can boost the SEO of a website. Is it just a marketing gimmick?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That raises a huge red flag for me. There is nothing you can do just by having a "server"  or any special software to improve SEO in the manner they are speaking. This sounds like they are using black hat techniques in an attempt to rank pages better. I would tell them to give you a detailed explanation of what this server does and if they don't tell you thank them for their time but you won't be needing their services.

Comment: Conde Thanks for putting My Question in right Manner. Correct but they said its not  Black hat Technique but they said they have a server which communicates with search engine (Google )

Comment: They are almost certainly lying to you. Google doesn't tolerate black at SEO at all and they certainly don't do special favors for a company like that. I very strongly recommend not using their services.

Answer (score 0):

There is no server software available that will do this for you correctly. Optimize your HTML, write good descriptions for your pages, and update your site daily with new content. If you are selling products, get reviews for them from your customers. There is only one good way to improve your rankings and it takes time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

The only legitimate thing they could mean would be that their server are fast, as load time is a factor in Google's ranking.  Your HTML, JavaScript, images, etc all need to be optimised as well.